# C# Json serialize

Tags: c#, .net, json

can you please help me how to create Json file in C# like in this example below? I have list of centres with list of rooms inside and inside of rooms is list of reservations (date of reservation is one of the elements of reservation). I don't know how to create from my list this data structure.

```
"data": [
{
  "meetingCentre": "EBC-MC_C7",
  "meetingRoom": "EBC-C7-MR:1_1",
  "reservations": {
    "28.10.2016": [
      {
        "from": "10:00",
        "to": "11:30",
        "expectedPersonsCount": 4,
        "customer": "College",
        "videoConference": false,
        "note": ""
      },
      {
        "from": "12:00",
        "to": "13:30",
        "expectedPersonsCount": 4,
        "customer": "College",
        "videoConference": false,
        "note": ""
      }
    ],
    "29.10.2016": [
      {
        "from": "10:00",
        "to": "11:30",
        "expectedPersonsCount": 4,
        "customer": "College",
        "videoConference": false,
        "note": ""
      }
    ]
  }
},
....
```

Comment: Use `Dictionary`? Where `key = 28.10.2016` and where `value` is list of objects.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I think it depends what what is the use case.
If you want to use it as DTO you should consider using a dictionary for reservation collection.

```
 public class Meeting
{
    public string MeetingCentre { get; set; }
    public string MeetingRoom { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, Reservation> ReservationSchedule { get; set; }
}

public class Reservation
{
    public string From { get; set; }
    //Other properties
}
```

To populate this object(if you are working with asp.net/core) you should read about model ModelBinders https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.2.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can take advantage of Newtonsoft.JSonConvert ?

My struct is a bit simplified (ex. strings instead of dates) but if you check the resulting json, it could meet your needs.

```
public class Class1
  {

    static void Main()
    {



      meetingCentre myCenter = new meetingCentre("EBC-MC_C7");
      meetingRoom myRoom = new meetingRoom("EBC-C7-MR:1_1");
      myCenter.rooms.Add(myRoom);
      myRoom.reservations.Add(new reservation("28.10.2016", "10:00", "11:30", 4, "College", false, ""));
      myRoom.reservations.Add(new reservation("28.10.2016", "12:00", "13:30", 4, "College", false, ""));
      myRoom.reservations.Add(new reservation("29.10.2016", "10:00", "11:30", 4, "College", false, ""));

      Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myCenter, Formatting.Indented));






      Console.ReadLine();
    }

  }


  public class meetingCentre
    {

      public List<meetingRoom> rooms = new List<meetingRoom>();

      public string id;

      public meetingCentre(string id)
      {
        this.id = id;
      }
    }

    public class meetingRoom
    {
      public List<reservation> reservations = new List<reservation>();
      public string id;

      public meetingRoom(string id)
      {
        this.id = id;
      }
    }

    public class reservation
    {

      public reservation(string d, string f, string t, int pc, string cust, bool v, string n)
      {
        date = d;
        from = f;
        to = t;
        expectedPersonsCount = pc;
        customer = cust;
        videoConference = v;
        note = n;

      }
      public string date { get; set; }
      public string from { get; set; }
      public string to { get; set; }
      public int expectedPersonsCount { get; set; }
      public string customer { get; set; }

      public bool videoConference { get; set; }
      public string note { get; set; }

    }

}
```